# How to store query(conditions) in variable using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to store query conditions in variable, beacuse same conditions can be used in different places so I created on function and used concatenation, but it is not storing any query condition.

Code:

```
 $records; // empty varaible to store all conditions using concatenation
     if ($val->id != '')
        $records .=$this->db->where('table.column', $val->id, true);
    
    if ($val->percentage != '')
        $records .=$this->db->or_where('table.column', $val->percentage, true);

  return $records;
```

Comment: What is `$records`?

Comment: @nice_dev empty variable

Comment: Have you tried `$records = "";` before the concatenations ?

Comment: @user_1234 You can't return query condition this way but rather just attach to `$this-db` before firing.

Comment: yes I tried $records='' but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
$query = $this->db->from('table')
if ($val->id != '')
    $query = $query->where('table.column', $val->id, true);
if ($val->percentage != '')
    $query = $query->or_where('table.column', $val->percentage, true);
$results = $query->get()->result();
```

Comment: I am writing nearly 10 conditions separated, and $this->db->from() in separate function

Comment: no issues, you just need to modify the same query variable. if `$this->db->from()` is in a separate function pass it as a parameter. it's like incrementing an integer variable. as long as you modifying the same variable, you should be able to call `get()` at the end.

Comment: you can't use `.=` since it doesn't return a string. value of $query is an query builder instance. `$query->where('table.column', $val->id, true)` modifies the properties of that instance